# What is the difference between .length() and .length()-1 when trying to count substrings?

Tags: java, string, substring, string-length

What is the difference between using .length() and .length()-1 to find how many times letters occur in a string?

example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) 
{
  if (str.substring(i, i + 1).equals("e")) 
  {
    count++;
  }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

vs

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) 
{
  if (str.substring(i, i + 2).equals("th")) 
  {
    count++;
  }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Why can't we just use str.length() for both?

Comment: *Why can't we just use str.length() for both?* - Because in the second condition, you've used `i + 2` instead of `i + 1` and therefore, if you do not use `i < str.length() - 1` in the second loop, the value of `i + 2` will exceed `str.length()` causing exception thrown from `str.substring(i, i + 2)`.

Comment: Because you will get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the second case.

Comment: If you have string like `abcd` there there are 4 single letters: `a` `b` `c` `d`, but at the same time there are 3 pairs of letters like `ab` `bc` `cd` (you can't create more). Now try to create formula for amount of series of length M in string with length N (if length is 1 letter there is N series, if length is 2 letters there is N-1 series, if length is M then there is [how many?] series).

Answer (score 1):

Because in the second example, you take a substring of 2 characters instead of one, like in the first example. Thus, by having the for loop only run until length - 1, the last iteration in the loop takes the characters at index length - 1 and length from the string. If you would check against length in the for loop, the substring in the last iteration would take the characters at position length and length + 1, which obviously wouldn't work.

Comment: To quote, Nigel from Spinal Tab, "it is one larger"

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that works for all substrings. It would look like:

```
int countSubstrings(String str, String s) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - s.length() + 1; i++) 
    {
      if (str.substring(i, i + s.length()).equals(s)) 
      {
        count++;
      }
    }
    return count;
}
```

You need to stop looping over the string earlier as the substring that you are checking becomes longer.

(Note: the above method can be implemented more efficiently - using [`String.regionMatches`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java11/java.base/java/lang/String.html#regionMatches(int,java.lang.String,int,int)) - but it's for illustrating you question)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, in this case:

```
count = 0;
for ( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    if (str.substring(i, i + 2).equals("th")) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

You will get the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 4, e
nd 6, length 5
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3756)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1902)
    at stackOverflow.Pattern.main(Pattern.java:22)
```

Because `i+2` would check for the `i+1` location of the string and that is beyond it's length.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use `str.length()` for the second one when it reaches the highest `i` value when it does a substring `i+2` will go off the end of `str`